# Snap SVG .animate callback fires immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to pass a set of arguments to an animate function within Snap SVG including a callback function. However, the callback (in this case is to remove the element) fires immediately on click and not after the animation has completed. As it is now, the element is removed and the animate function then errors because the element no longer exists. Any ideas?

```
    var theCallback = theApp.destroyAnElement("#"+ theParentID); 

//The function call
theAnimationFunctions.animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap('.stopped','#svg-container',{transform: 's1,0'}, 500, mina.backin, 0,0,theCallback);

// The animate function
    animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap: function(element, parentSVG, animationValues, duration, easing, initialDelay, callback) {
       var s = Snap.select("#"+ parentSVG),
           theElement = s.select(element);

       setTimeout(function() {
         theElement.stop().animate(animationValues, duration, easing, function() {
             callback;
         });
      }, initialDelay);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
theCallback = function () { theApp.destroyAnElement("#"+ theElementID); };

theAnimationFunctions.animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap('.stopped','#svg-container',{transform: 's1,0'}, 500, mina.backin, 0,0,theCallback);

theAnimationFunctions = {
    animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap: function(element, parentSVG, animationValues, duration, easing, initialDelay, callback) {
    var s = Snap.select("#"+ parentSVG),
    theElement = s.select(element);

    setTimeout(function() {
       theElement.stop().animate(animationValues, duration, easing, function() {
            callback();
       });
    }, initialDelay);
}
```

With the updates above, I now get an error at the completion of the animation:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function"
```

Comment: Do you define `theCallback` _after_ calling `theAnimationFunctions.animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap` ? If so, `theCallback` will be `undefined` on the invocation, which is indeed `not a function`.

Comment: theCallback is defined before the function call - just poor pasting on my part.

Comment: It looks like the parameters and arguments of `animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap: function(element, parentSVG, animationValues, duration, easing, initialDelay, callback) {` do not match up with the call site `theAnimationFunctions.animateSingleSVGElementWithSnap('.stopped','#svg-container',{transform: 's1,0'}, 500, mina.backin, 0,0,theCallback);
`. The call site has one extra parameter and `callback` is probably getting assigned the penultimate argument, i.e. `0`.

Comment: That was it. Stupid mistake.  Thank you for explaining the bigger issue though with the function call itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the callback in an anonymous function to prevent it from firing immediately:

```
var theCallback = function () { theApp.destroyAnElement("#"+ theParentID); };
```

And then call it as a function:

```
theElement.stop().animate(animationValues, duration, easing, function() {
         theCallback(); // <-- notice the parenthesis
     });
```

Comment: This definitely makes sense. However, this does throw a "callback is not a function" error.

Comment: @Yuschick It shouldn't. Can you please update your question with more code, specifying where the error shows up?

Comment: @Musicall_ut I have posted an update of the code and error.